# angular 1.2.4 directive can not bind data with HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Today i update the angular 1.2.4,
but i have some public logic directive.
These directive do not have template or templateurl ,  but have some dom in the html,

like this： sf-task-comment is a directive

```
<div sf-task-comment="taskBasicInfo">
        <div>
           {{ vm | json }}
           …………SOME DOM………… 
        </div>
</div>
```

but , i found after i update the angular version . 
This stuff can't work ?

HTML cant bind $scope data.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you post what `sf-task-comment` does? Does it have a `template`? Were you trying to do transclusion which doesn't work now?

Comment: sf-task-comment  don't have template  and have  isolate scope